# Why is this question showing up in the Linked section?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-questions

I have asked a [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)-related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62474057/10155936). However, in the linked section [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62428604/10155936) question which I have previously asked also shows up.

I have not mentioned the link or referenced the latter question anywhere in the former question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Linked" section is bidirectional; your link in the comments of the later question to the former question causes them both to be linked to each other.